# Apache CXF wadl2java could not find main class WADLToJava

Tags: cxf, wadl

I need to convert wadl to java pojo, for that i have downloaded apache cxf 3.0.1 version. But when i run wadl2java bat file in my command prompt, i am getting following exception

```
D:\software\apache-cxf-3.0.1\bin>wadl2java -h
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.WADLToJava
```

Here this script file is looking for WADLToJava class. i have downloaded the apache cxf source distribution, i can see that wadl2java class is there. Please suggest me how i can use apache cxf to generate java files from wadl url.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `CFX_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` environments variables.

CXF_HOME should be your installation dir, in your example;

```
      CXF_HOME=D:\software\apache-cxf-3.0.1\
```

CLASSPATH is variable used for setting java classpath for wadl2java script, in your windows example;

```
      CLASSPATH=.;%CXF_HOME%\lib\*
```